# HTML Purifier Special Characters Question?

Tags: special-characters, htmlpurifier

How do I display this in `&#169;` html purifier instead of this all the time ©. In other words how do I display both in html purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/?

Comment: You should post some code; if your setup is different than the demo we'll have a tough time figuring out what you're doing. I suspect you're doing an inappropriate html_entity_decode.

Answer (score 0):

&#169;

If your using firefox select the above code, right click and click on view selection source.

or

You should write & amp ; #169; altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
&#169; &amp;#169;
```

Here is a screenshot from the HTMLPurify demo page, showing the result.
[Purify http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9791/purify.jpg](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/9791/purify.jpg)

Comment: My code is not the demo I know I tested it. The demo has some extra coding of some sort.